# std::unique_copy with overlapping ranges

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
OutputIt unique_copy( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                      OutputIt d_first );
```

Is it valid to use `std::unique_copy` if input range and output range overlap?
Consider the following two example cases

`auto d_last = std::unique_copy(first, last, d_first);`

1. `d_first <= first <= d_last <= last`
2. `first <= d_first <= last <= d_last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preconditions for `std::unique_copy` are described in
[[algorithms#alg.unique-8]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms#alg.unique-8):

> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
>   constexpr OutputIterator
>     unique_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                 OutputIterator result);
> ```
>
> *Preconditions*:
>
> - The ranges `[first, last)` and `[result, result+(last-first))` do not overlap.

So this is undefined behavior.